# Issue with Microsoft.Maui.Core 7.0.101

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, maui, .net-7.0

i need your help.

I have a maui project in .NET7 that work perfectly when i launch it on my develop pc.
But for a few days (after updating visual studio to version 17.4), when I publish the project by creating the msix package I get the following message after the installation (which ends without problems):

[image]

By clicking yes I will be redirected to this page: [Page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-desktop-7.0.15-windows-x86-installer?cid=getdotnetcore)

I download the package and install without errors. But the problem is not resolved and the above message reappears again.

Can someone help me?

Comment: That's probably because Maui .Net7 is probably out of support

Comment: Creata a .net 8 project and move the code into it, see if it wil work well?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JianweiSun-MSFT, i try it and this message doesn't appear

Comment: Great! Congratulations on solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as an answer:

> I have a maui project in .NET7 that work perfectly when i launch it on my develop pc. But for a few days (after updating visual studio to version 17.4), when I publish the project by creating the msix package I get the following message after the installation (which ends without problems)

Using the latest version: .NET 8 can fix the problem.